# What’s the difference between בכי and דמעה? Also, are there additional terms for tears in לשון הקודש

Tags: translation

Is there a difference between בכי and דמעה and if yes, what is it?

Comment: Crying (voice) and tears (eyes)?

Comment: Also, I understood from Reb Moshe Shapiro that *bechiyah* relates to the word *navuch*, confused. So that people cry when they do not know how to progress with life, they are presented with confusion. *Dema* can also mean mixture. So that people also cry when there is a intractable mixture of good and evil, i.e. good has been subsumed into the mixture of good and evil that exists in the world, and it has not been possible to extricate and thereby save the good.